# Bulk redirect old products pages

Tags: redirects, 301-redirect

I tried reselling some products from a company and added all their products to my site
After a year I desided to give up on it and want to remove all these products...
Some of them still show up on google searches but i want to get rid of them. I want to know what would be the best action?

Should I just remove the product pages?
Should I create some general redirect on all these products im removing to the shop page or somthing like that?
Is removing these products a bad idea?

Comment: Remove the pages and let them 404. It will take a bit of time, however, that is the best thing you can do. Be patient and do not worry.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps creating a page with the message that you are no longer selling these products and to continue to the home page or other selling page? Then 301 redirect all of those product pages. Google will update them fairly quickly. Then after no one is